# Layout not scrolling up?

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried everything but my layout is not scrolling. I wanted to scroll whole page not just the `GridView`. Please if anyone can help me to resolve this. 
I tried to make `ScrollView` as parent as well as child of relative layout but it won't work for me. I don't want to change my layout but I just want to scroll the layout so that I can add more `CardViews`.

Here is my code of layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/bg">

    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="7"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_weight="1.4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textGrid"
                    android:text="SCHOOL NAME"
                    android:textSize="34sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="3"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:padding="14dp">

                <!-- Row 1 -->
                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/me_time"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Me"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/family_time"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Family"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/lovely_time"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Lovely"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/team_time"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Team"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/friends"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Friends"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <ImageView
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                        <TextView
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do not use `android:weightSum` and `android:weigh` inside `ScrollView` . This is quite opposite of what `scrollview` is build for .

Comment: Can you use LinearLayout instead of GridLayout ?

Comment: change height of grid layout to 1000dp, Makes your scroll view working...

Comment: if I am not using weight property in relative layout then the layout is changing when i run it. It only show SCHOOL NAME on whole page...help..

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.Scroll working fine now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/bg">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textGrid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="SCHOOL NAME"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="34sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:padding="14dp"
                android:rowCount="3">

                <!-- Row 1 -->
                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/me_time" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Me"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/family_time" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Family"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/lovely_time" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Lovely"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/team_time" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Team"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <!-- Row 2 -->

                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/friends" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Friends"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <!-- Column 2 -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@mipmap/calendar" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Calendars"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="18sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </GridLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks...it's working. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote you.

Comment: if I am not using weight property in relative layout then the layout is changing when i run it. It only show SCHOOL NAME on whole page...help..

Comment: @Krishna Just copy above code and use i already checked in layout school name label and below your cards.